# Deploy java springboot to Docker has error invalid ELF header

Tags: java, docker, pkcs#11

My code java has a config to call dll file.
After deploy used Docker, I also push this file to container.
But when run, Docker has error without everything ok in local.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: /cs_pkcs11_R2.dll: invalid ELF header/cs_pkcs11_R2.dll
at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.connect(Native Method)
at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.<init>(PKCS11.java:144)
at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.getInstance(PKCS11.java:157)
at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:313)
```

My code call this file

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("name=" + nameLib);
builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
builder.append("library=\"" + library + "\"");<- path to dll file
builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
builder.append("slot=" + slot);        
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(builder.toString().getBytes());
provider = new SunPKCS11(bais); <- Exception here
Security.addProvider(provider);
```

Comment: You’ll need to compile the library for Linux.

Comment: ...a `.dll` file sounds like a Windows dynamically-linked library, but in a Linux container you'd need a Linux `.so` shared object file.

Comment: Thanks for help. I change .so shared object file and program run ok.